# Enabling PHP extension mb_string for UniserverZ on Windows

Tags: php, windows, netbeans

I'm setting up NetBeans for PHP development on Windows. I've chosen UniserverZ as the PHP interpreter for local testing/debugging.

To test it I selected the ToDoList example. I get a fatal error:

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function TodoList\mb_internal_encoding()

There are lots of Answered questions on this issue, basically saying that php_mbstring.dll has to be in the php folder and

extension=php_mbstring.dll

must be in  php.ini, **and enabled**. It's the **enabled** part that has stumped me, because the given "answers" say to use "yum install php-mbstring"
where "yum" appears to be a Linux command-line thing, whereas I work with Windows.

So, how can I enable this in my environment, namely Windows 10, NetBeans, UniserverZ?

Ed

Comment: I have PHP 5.6.5 and 7.1.3 on windows and they both came with php_mbstring.dll in the ext dir.

Comment: In php.ini remove the `;` from in front of `extension=php_mbstring.dll`

Comment: Thanks. In my case the dlls unzipped into the extensions directory.

Comment: Also, there are 3 .ini files. php_test.ini, php_development.ini, and php_production.ini. There is a UniController.exe that allows selection of which one is to be actually used. The ; is absent in all 3. Are you using UniserverZ